# How should I define or write my function in Haskell with function composition?

Tags: function, haskell, composition, pointfree

I defined a function in Haskell,which is supposed to square and then add 1 to all numbers in a given list.I wanted to write that function with function composition but unfortunately it doesn't work with dot beetwen functions but it works when i write my functions with brackets.I don't understand why it doesn't work with dot or rather why doesn't it work with function composition?

```
square :: Int -> Int
square x = x * x

funSqr :: [Int] -> [Int]
funSqr xs = [(square x) | x <- xs]

funAdd1 :: [Int] -> [Int]
funAdd1 xs = [(x + 1) | x <- xs]

funFoldr :: [Int] -> Int 
funFoldr [] = 0
funFoldr (x:xs) = x + (funFoldr xs)

fun :: [Int] -> Int
fun xs = funFoldr(funAdd1(funSqr xs))
```

But

```
fun :: [Int] -> Int
fun xs = funFoldr.funAdd1.funSqr xs  --Why on earth doesn't it work ?
fun xs = funFoldr.funRek xs        --or rather this way?
```

Could someone lighten my path ?

Thanks a lot 
Asena

Comment: Try `fun = funFoldr . funAdd1 . funSqr`

Comment: Try `fun = sum . map ((+1) . join (*))` after `import Control.Monad (join)`.

Answer (score 6):

Haskell parsing rules 101: function application binds more tightly than any infix operator. The amount of whitespace does not matter. So

```
funFoldr.funAdd1.funSqr xs
   ≡ funFoldr . funAdd1 . funSqr xs
   ≡ funFoldr . funAdd1 . (funSqr xs)
```

Now, `funSqr xs` is not a function anymore (just the *result* of applying a function to `xs`). You can't compose things that aren't functions.

What you meant to try is this, and it does indeed work:

```
(funFoldr.funAdd1.funSqr) xs
```

More commonly, this is written

```
funFoldr . funAdd1 . funSqr $ xs
```

or

```
funFoldr . funAdd1 $ funSqr xs
```

Alternative, you can avoid the `funSqr xs` grouping if you simply don't mention `xs`:

```
fun :: [Int] -> Int
fun = funFoldr . funAdd1 . funSqr
```

This is called *point-free style*.